# How to use -v trigger in svnant log task?

Tags: svn, ant, svnant

in my Ant build script, I'm using svnant to retrieve SVN logs for specific directories; now I want to see the changed files, too. I tried

```
<svn username="${svn.username}" password="${svn.password}" failonerror="true">
  <log path="${dir}" destFile="${dest}" asXml="false" verbose="true" />
</svn>
```

and failed miserably with

> log doesn't support the "verbose"
>   attribute

After some research I found out that someone already tried to implement this ([source](http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1043&dsMessageId=863607)) but the svn log of the log command source (hey, recursion!) says

> ~ dropped the 'verbose' attribute on
>   commands as this option is passed by
>   the ant execution

Perhaps I'm thinking only inside the box, but I just don't get it ... where do I pass this option? 
If I can't pass it in my ant script, is there a possibility to force svnant log to be verbose apart from tampering with the source and compiling my own svnant?

Answer (score 0):

We use code like this to get a file list:

```
<svn refid="svn.settings">
   <log url="${env.SVN_URL}" startRevision="${start.revision}" stopRevision="${env.SVN_REVISION}" changedPathes="true" destFile="${svn.changed.files.xml}" />
</svn>
```

Based on the differences between your code and ours I'd expect the following to work:

```
<svn username="${svn.username}" password="${svn.password}" failonerror="true">
   <log path="${dir}" startRevision="${start.revision}" stopRevision="${env.SVN_REVISION}" changedPathes="true" destFile="${dest}" />
</svn>
```

The start and stop revision may not be needed and thus you would have:

```
<svn username="${svn.username}" password="${svn.password}" failonerror="true">
   <log path="${dir}" changedPathes="true" destFile="${dest}" />
</svn>
```